# Div auto adjust according to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have design similar  to below given link. when i open this link and minimize or maximize the browser then it div box adjust their position accordingly. i am finding the same kind of jQuery or JavaScript. I tried to download it but it is not working in IE 7 and i also want to know name of this kind of jQuery

```
http://berndkammerer.com/
```

Comment: Try F12 (or View | Source if you have a really old browser).

Comment: Using an inspector and performing a quick search points me to a plugin called [vgrid](http://blog.xlune.com/2009/09/vgrid/demo001.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://isotope.metafizzy.co

Answer (score 1):

You may use [**jQuery Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) a custom jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)